# FOUR-algebra - boolean algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Belnap’s logic contains the the truth values 'true' ($t$), 'false' ($f$), 'unknown' ($\bot$) and 'paradox' ($\top$). Each of these is represented by a pair of bits:

\begin{align}
t &\rightarrow (1,0) \\
f &\rightarrow (0,1) \\
\bot &\rightarrow (0,0) \\
\top &\rightarrow (1,1)
\end{align}

The operations are defined as follows:

\begin{align}
\land &: \bigl((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\bigr) &&\rightarrow \bigl(\min(x_1,x_2), \max(y_1,y_2)\bigr) \\
\lor &: \bigl((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\bigr) &&\rightarrow \bigl(\max(x_1,x_2), \min(y_1,y_2)\bigr) \\
\lnot &: (x,y) &&\rightarrow (y,x)
\end{align}

I am wondering, whether Belnap’s four valued-valued logic, with the set of truth values $\{t,f,\bot,\top\}$ and the operations $\land,\lor,\lnot$ is a boolean algebra, and if so why?

EDIT: The complements-rule ($a ∨ ¬a = 1$ and $a ∧ ¬a = 0$) doesn’t work, does it?

Comment: This must be a homework problem somewhere: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352967/is-belnaps-four-valued-logic-a-boolean-algebra/1352984#1352984 (What's the "complements rule"?)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the complements axioms $a\vee \neg a=1$ and $a\wedge \neg a=0$ do not work.  A really quick way to see this is that those axioms imply $a\neq \neg a$ (unless $0=1$ in which case the Boolean algebra can only have one element), but $\bot$ and $\top$ do satisfy $a=\neg a$.

Note that if you ignore the given definition of $\neg$, then you actually do have a Boolean algebra (just with a different definition of negation).  Indeed, if you flip the values of the second bits (so $t$ is written as $(1,1)$, $f$ as $(0,0)$, $\bot$ as $(0,1)$, and $\top$ as $(1,0)$), then the operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ just become the usual Boolean operations on $\{0,1\}^2$ (namely, coordinatewise min and max, respectively).  The correct negation operation for this Boolean algebra is coordinatewise negation, in other words $\neg(x,y)=(1-x,1-y)$ (a formula which does not change if you flip all values of the second bit).